# SQL last n entrys + latest bottom

Tags: sql, select

I want to select the lastest 8 entrys out of my table "testuser1". My problem is that the latest entry is displayed on the top, but i want it at the bottom.
Has anyone an idea?

```
$sql = "SELECT MESSAGE_TEXT, SENTDATE FROM testuser1 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 8";
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the 8 records, and then order them in the outer query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT MESSAGE_TEXT, SENTDATE
      FROM testuser1
      ORDER BY ID DESC
      LIMIT 8
     ) t
ORDER BY ID ASC;
```